# gstreamer-rust library libgobject-2.0.0.dylib not loaded

Tags: rust, gstreamer, gstreamer-rs

Trying to run the tutorials of [gstreamer-rs](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer-rs)

getting the error

`dyld[62967]: Library not loaded:... @rpath/libgobject-2.0.0.dylib '/usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.0.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)`

libgobject-2.0.dylib is part of **/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Versions/1.0/lib**

*Cargo.toml*

```
[package]
name = "gstreamerDemo"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
glib = { git = "https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk-rs-core" }
gdk = { git = "https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk3-rs", optional = true }
gtk = { git = "https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk3-rs", optional = true }

gst = { version = "0.20.2", package = "gstreamer" }

[target.'cfg(target_os = "macos")'.dependencies]
cocoa = "0.24"
objc = "0.2.7"
```

*code* (minimal)

```
#[path = "../common.rs"]
mod tutorials_common;

fn tutorial_main() {
    // Initialize GStreamer
    gst::init().unwrap();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

adding a symbolic link to the files under `/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Versions/1.0/lib` did the trick like:

```
sudo ln -s /Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Versions/1.0/lib/*.dylib /usr/local/lib/
```

I do prefer a better solution like dynamic linkage, If anyone can post a working example, I will accept that as a solution

Comment: Thank for your solution, i was stuck with the same problem, coming from XCode. Did you manage to find any better solution?